# the $emit Vue method on parent does't work , but on child it works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, vue-component

i have a component register and add event @submit.prevent inside the template by $emit , i tried to console.log on the inisde method component, it was works, but when on my main js, it does not work and nothing, but not error

this is my component example :

```
Vue.component("register", {
  props: {
    form: Object
  },
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 offset-4">
        <form @submit.prevent="goRegister">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameRegister" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter username" v-model.trim="form.username" required>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
  methods: {
    goRegister() {
      this.$emit("doRegister", this.form);
    }
  }
});
```

this is my parent on my html :

```
 <register v-on:do-register="handleRegister" :form="forms"> </register>
```

and on my  vue main js

```
new Vue({
   data:{
   forms: {
      username: null,
      email: null,
      password: null,
      name: null,
      age: null
}
}, 
methods : {
    handleRegister() {
      console.log(this.forms.username);
    }
}
})
```

i tried to console that method **handleRegister**, but nothing happened and not error, 
is that something missing on my parent component ??

Answer (score 2):

Just rename the event you are emitting: VueJS does not convert between camelCase and kebab-case for emitted event names. If you want to listen to the `do-register` event, you need to emit the event as `do-register` and not `doRegister`:

```
this.$emit('do-register', this.form);
```

---

What if you still want to emit a `doRegister` event? In that case, you will need to emit it as an all-lowercase string.

Note that bound event names inline has to be case-insensitive, [due to a limitation in HTML, where attribute names are case-insensitive—the browser actually converts it to lowercase](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4688#issuecomment-271752719). Therefore, if you still prefer to emit an event without using the kebab-case nomenclature, then you will need to do:

```
this.$emit('doregister', this.form);
```

And in the consuming parent's template, you will need to listen to the `doregister` event:

```
<register v-on:doregister="handleRegister" :form="forms"> </register>
```